# Viewmodel contents null after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC application. I am currently developing a search page where both the search box and the table of results are displayed on the same page. To do this I have used Partial Views and AJAX/JSON calls with a viewmodel. After entering the two search terms in the textbox, both are null in the controller after being passed through ajax.

Here is the code:

ViewModel:

```
public class ExampleViewModel
{
    public string search { get; set; }
    public string search2 { get; set; }

}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Search(ExampleViewModel searchTerm)
    {
        var searchList = db.UserLists.Where(x => x.LastName.Contains(searchTerm.search));

        return PartialView("_SearchResultsPartial", searchList);
    }
```

Body of Index View:

```
<body>
<div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.search)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.search2)
    <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="return getSearchResults()"/>

</div>

<div id="search-results">

</div>

<script>
    var exViewModel = {
        search: $('#search').val(),
        search2: $('#search2').val()
    }

    function getSearchResults() {        

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(exViewModel),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url : "/View/Search/",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#search-results").html(result);
        }
    });
    }


</script>
```

Again, after setting a breakpoint on the Search [POST] method, the ExampleViewModel's terms are null.

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer, suggest you just wrap the elements in `<form>` and use `data: $('form').serialize(),` (and remove `contentType: "application/json",`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At first sight, it seems that you have to retrieve the values within the function scope:

```
function getSearchResults() {        
    //Read these values on button click
    var exViewModel = { 
        search: $('#search').val(),
        search2: $('#search2').val()
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(exViewModel),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url : "/View/Search/",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#search-results").html(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Otherwise, the `exViewModel` is just determined on page load.